# How to position something absolutely in the same way regardless of the content height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, absolute

I have this:

[image]

but then if I remove an option I get this:

[image]

I want a way where no matter the options number the gap above is always the same

So far I have:

```
 <div
            className={css`
              position: absolute;
              margin-top: -150px;
              background: #fff;
              width: 100%;
              box-shadow: 0 0 0 0, 0 0 2px 0 rgba(43, 45, 80, 0.08),
                0 1px 1.5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07),
                0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
            `}
          >
            <div
              className={css`
                padding: 8px;
              `}
            >
              Option 1
            </div>
            <div
              className={css`
                padding: 8px;
              `}
            >
              Option 2
            </div>
            <div
              className={css`
                padding: 8px;
              `}
            >
              Option 3
            </div>
          </div>
```

where I'm forcing the margin-top. if I use `top: -90px` the same thing happens. (ignore that it's not dynamic and hardcoded divs as options for now). how do I make position absolute dynamic based on the height? the parent div just has: `display: flex, position: relative` on it. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to use postion:relative instead of position:absolute

Comment: how would that achieve it?

Comment: when you will set the red bouton position relative it will deplace realtively to the above div